# Using Qt Creator in QML Design mode, how to reference an image using qrc path?

Tags: qt, resources, qt-creator, qml

So, we have an embedded Linux system running Qt and we compile all of our icons (.png format) into our executable using the resource file.  The problem is that I want to be able to use the Qt Creator QML Designer to visually see our screens as we are laying them out, but it only allows me to select a relative file system path (i.e. not a path to the resource).  If I go to edit mode and put the qrc:/image.png it works in run time but the image doesn't show up in the QML Design mode.  Has anyone ever done this or know if it is possible?

Comment: Docs suggest your approach is correct: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html#resource-collection-files

Comment: Can you give us some code sample, to see what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

There is at least a workaround:

Put everything in the resource file (the qml files and the icons), and when you'll edit the file in Qt Quick Designer, all paths will be relative so the icons will be visible.

Everything is described there: [Managing resource files with the Qt resource system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#managing-resource-files-with-the-qt-resource-system)

And to avoid deploying the qml files, you'll have to remove/comment the following line from your .pro:

```
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01
```

and replace it with:

```
OTHER_FILES = <list of qml files>
```